# ASP.NET validators validate on mouse up

Tags: asp.net

I have a compare validator on a Password field compared it to a password repeat field.  If there is a validation error the error doesn't disappear until the lost focus event is fired.  The client wants this changed to be the key up event.

What is the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doable as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#TextBox1').keyup(function () {
            if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                Page_ClientValidate();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Edited: Changed mouseup to keyup.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem like there is likely to even be a mouse click in this case. After the field is filled out the user would either tab or click to the next box..in either case the previous box would lose focus and fire the validator...unless i am missing something.

Other than that i'd say javascript is your answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant key up event, not thinking straight today.

Comment: Ohh ok..that makes sense now. Looks like the answer from @gbs might be the ticket...Javascript/JQuery